# how to get a image upload option for ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am not able to insert file manager and image upload option for ckeditor, please can some one share the php code for that, i tried to make this, not getting upload image option

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a plugin in your ckeditor to image upload,
there are many image upload plugins available for ckeditor 2 are here

1. [simpleuploads-plugin-for-ckeditor](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.in/p/simpleuploads-plugin-for-ckeditor.html)  [Demo](http://www.martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/simpleuploads.demo4/).
2. [ckfinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder)